# Confusing checkboxes and radio buttons

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, layout, html

I have a problem building a certain UI for a website. I'm going to demonstrate the problem with a simple website for a restaurant chain:

### Context

the website has many users and many restaurants. Each restaurant has certain users assigned to it, where the user could be either a manager, a cook or a waiter.

the waiter can see the addresses of the orders that come in, the cook can see that **and** the content of the orders (what the food is), and the manager can see both these things **and** can change the roles of any user.

There can only be **one** manager for every restaurant, but as many cooks and waiters as desired. Here's how the UI looks like as of now:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKUHWF.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

### Problem

Users can only have **one** role each, since every role has all the privileges of the previous roles plus a new privilege. So no one can be both a waiter and a cook, or a cook and a manager etc. That isn't very clear using the UI above, since one could check two checkboxes for the same user, or even all three roles.

### Question

How do you you make this idea clear through the UI? 'the idea' being the there can only be **one** manager for a restaurant, and every user can have only **one** role.

This is my first post here by the way, so I hope I'm in the right place.
Thanks for responses in advance!

EDIT: There are higher roles that can change all three mentioned roles freely.

The last case is what I'm trying to avoid (Mary).

[image].

Comment: Who sees the screen that you posted? Is it 'admin', 'manager','cook' or 'waiter'? I think the UI could be further simplified based on each role.

Comment: Actually both manager and cook, which doesn't make sense in this example, but in the real world case, both roles have the same privileges, so the accepted answer is already perfect (the real role that corresponds to 'waiter' can't access the screen I posted or change roles at all). Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Right now, your permissions are entirely hierarchical... but I wouldn't assume that's always going to be the case. Some of your waiters are under 18/21 and can't serve alcohol. Waiters will need authorization to use the credit card machine, but cooks won't. Maybe later you'll add some sort of weird sushi counter where the cook *does* need to be able to use the card machine, but you still don't trust your other cooks with it. Permissions can be a huge rabbit hole, but in general you want as much granularity as you can get - typically a boolean yes/no for individual permissions.

Comment: Of course, for convenience reasons, you'll often also have a "role" system of some sort, to be able to give someone "all the standard waiter permissions" with one click, etc.

Comment: Since every role excludes itself just have a choicebox for each user?

Comment: how  frequently are these roles going to be changed? what would be more useful, to visualize easily who is in a particular role at a particular moment or to change a role of an employee?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In a scenario like this I would make the UI reflect the possible states of the application. You can only have one manager so there should only be one place to select a manager, everyone else can either be a cook or a server, so provide mutually exclusive UI widgets for those states. Here's an example:

[image: Mockup]

In practice you might want to make it a little more deliberate to change people's roles, but hopefully that at least conveys the idea.

**Edit:** As some comments have mentioned that there are design problems with this mockup, and I don't recommend a direct implementation of it. Please be aware that the mockup was only meant to answer the OP's question and that other design principles still apply here.

Some exercises for the reader include:

1. Eliminate ambiguity in which role is currently selected
2. Display the manager's information (phone, email, ...)
3. Make data changing operations more deliberate than simply changing a dropdown or toggle

Comment: I have seen this widget a few times and the first thing we did after few usability tests and a small chat with technical support guys has been to... **nuke them from the orbit**. Even if, in theory, color should make clear which one is selected then at least half users (of our samples + customers) were NOT SURE about which state is on and which state is off. Not to mention color blind people. Definitely a no-no for me, if you really need to use color it should be a PLUS, not the only medium to communicate this information

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Not to mention that colour-only representations break WCAG, if that's something you care about. An alternative or addition, ironically, might be a check mark next to the selected role. But the principle of separating the manager out is still valid.

Comment: With this layout, you don't see the contact information for the manager at all. As a manager, I'd want to make sure my contact info is readily available.

Comment: Replacing the Cook/Server toggle with a dropdown would clear up any confusion over which is the active state, and also easily accommodate any role additions later on (e.g. what happens when they add a Washer role?).

Comment: When you change manager on this view, you'll have to re-render the whole table, all the rows will move, and a new row will appear, which the user needs to interact with. e.g. if I change John to be the manager, Alice needs to appear as a row in the table, and the user needs to select her role. And if I do it by mistake, can I get John's old role back? Will I know if I have done so? -1 from me.

Comment: Still the best suggestion. The color confusion could easily be solved by replacing the toggles with the same simple radio buttons I used in my picture, and that's actually what I'm planning to do. About re-rendering: when another user is selected for the manager, his row will be replaced with a row for the current manager, and will 'glow' green for a short time, to get attention. That way no rows have to move. Another point is, the whole interface is actually a popup with a save button, so if the user did something by mistake and wants to undo, he can simply click Cancel.

Comment: @JasonTowne Have the list control sort the manager to the top.

Comment: I had no idea I would get so much response to this quick and dirty answer! @AdrianoRepetti I agree with your comments, excepting that the widget shouldn't function any differently for the color blind. It's equally confusing for lots of different types of users, but that's only one of many problems with that five minute mockup. I wouldn't recommend copying the sample one for one to anyone, but I think it did an adequate job of conveying the idea I was presenting.

Comment: One caveat: I think a dropdown is too easy/flimsy for a **big** change like switching manager. A manager change will probably not happen too often - and will require additional action (assigning a new role to the former manager) - so it should probably be locked behind a button or some other form of *do an action* component. A change in a dropdown doesn't *feel* like an action with big consequences...

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but it would have been similar to this, with a few changes. (1) Get rid of the horrible colour-toggles and use ordinary radio buttons instead. (2) Give the manager her own row in the table, so that (a) you can see her contact details, and (b) you don't have any re-rendering  or re-ordering issues when you select a different manager. (3) In the manager's row in the table, have the radio buttons for "Cook" or "Wait staff", so that you can see what the manger's role will become if someone replaces her as manager; but have the radio buttons disabled and greyed out.

Answer (score 106):

Since the change of current Manager is an action invalidating the other options - I would present it in a manner which communicates clear what is about to happen.

Waiter/Chef are Radio-Buttons, so only one of them can be active at a time - and only one person can be manager and nothing else.

[image: Example For Manager with Button]

Comment: Very nice suggestion! The separation of (Manager) from (Waiter and Chef) makes a lot clearer!

Comment: And you can still combine it with nicer Radio-Buttons, maybe with little icons and grouped closer together - the important part is the clear action "replace manager" - following the rule: *If a user action is special enough that no usual icon describes it adequately, write it out for them!*

Comment: Clear distinction between manager role and other set of roles (For instance: Chef and Waiter) is really fine rather than moving out the manager role from the table.  From UX point of view, this works.

Comment: Actually I found moving the Manager role out to be cleaner. I feel that adding it on every row would clutter the UI a little more than a simple dropdown at the top. Still both are smart and practical.

Comment: All I see is Mikey, Johnny, Sarah and Lisa in line to "Replace Manager". Can't be comfortable for Bobby Bob.

Comment: If there could be multiple managers one day with the same hierarchy level, Falco's model here will be easily extensible (making the manager button a toggle button; defaulting to an unassigned state when unticking it & needing to assign all users to complete form, probably). But if not, move the option out like OP suggests.

Answer (score 21):

This seems like a user grouping task.

Both of these examples have the nice property that you can print out a similar view to display in the kitchen. You also don't have any duplicated / redundant text of Cook / Waiter over the whole UI, so I think it's easier to read and understand who is working with who.

#### Tag style

Similar to how you add tags to a Stack Exchange question.

[image]

#### Menu style

I took the WordPress menu editing as a base concept to simulate hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Use this - 
This is a higher role view.

In manager's view, the manager won't have a combo-box for his/her role.
The view of other two will be plain text - no combo-boxes.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVEHnq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Very nice suggestion, I would up vote it if I had the reputation. Although one problem remains: that it's not visually clear that there can only be one manager, which it was in the original view. Still the best suggestion though, thanks.

Comment: @H.Saleh You can do that by removing the Manager option from the list when a manager role is selected for one employee.

Comment: I like this solution, but it's not as clear at a glance how many waiters and cooks you have as in the original question.

Comment: But how can you switch the manager role between employees then?

Comment: I think it's difficult to quickly change the manager role in this view.

Answer (score 4):

From what I see they all should be radio buttons (use better spacing to divide the each user and associated radio buttons).
The question, in your head, should be:
Who is Alice? Is she a (•)Manager, a ()Cook or a ()Waiter?
Who is Bob? Is he a ()Manager, a (•)Cook or a ()Waiter?
etc.

We read from left to right, so you first notice the user and only then the roles. And as there can be only one role per user, then they all should be radio buttons

Comment: But how do you convey that there should only be one manager? Or how do you disallow picking two users as managers?

Comment: Is explanatory text an option? For example "Please note: Each user can be assigned to only one role. There can be only one manager." The second question is, why would people pick more than one manager? There must be a reason. Many restaurants I've visited have more than one manager. It's necessary for giving people days off, but to also always have a manager in the restaurant

Comment: The text is definitely an option, but i was hoping for a better visual way :) Now about the whole restaurant thing, it was just an example to clear the idea :) The actual case i'm working with includes company property that needs to be maintained. So there are people who watch over these assets (the 'waiters' in my example) and they report to their officials about errors/malfunctions. There are many officials, but there's also a "Main official" whose name is associated with the asset, so that's where the 'Cooks' and 'Manager' come from.

Comment: I would imagine that the administrator knows that there can be only one manager, so you might not need to programmatically constrain that. (Might there be situations where you'll have two managers, each doing a half shift? Making your constraints too strict can make the system unusable in the real world.)

Comment: Unfortunately that's what the client asked for :) I also forgot to mention a minor detail, that the 'Cooks' can also assign users and managers. Of course it doesn't make any sense in this context, but in the asset context, both 'cooks' and 'managers' correspond to Administrators. The 'manager' is simply the main name associated with the asset, in case of an Excel export for example. So no, the solution still doesn't apply, but again, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: If someone will use this method (I believe the other answers have better UX) but you could always have a group of radio buttons for Manager and a group of radio buttons for Cook/Waiter per user and just disable the Cook/Waiter option for the manager while keeping the OP's current format.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution by using iOS segmentation concept along with disable status. I think it is visually understandable yet serves the purpose.

[image]